# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path' in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe', options=option)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Output:

```
WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

I'm trying to create a script to log in to a website. When I try to run this script, it gives me this error:
`WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'`

Answer (score 65):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `executable_path` was removed.

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 21):

Note: Remove `executable_url` from the argument, because you have installed the latest version of Selenium if you have Selenium above the 4.6.0, you don't need to add `executable_url`, and in the latest version of Selenium, you don't need to download **webdriver**.

Just copy the below code and run the your Python file simple.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `executable_path`(see below), if you do not wish to set the `driver.exe` path manually. With the latest Selenium (v4.6.0 and onwards), its in-built tool, known as `SeleniumManger`, can download and handle the `driver.exe` if you do not specify.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = option)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 2):

I helped solve this in this GitHub post: *[self.driver = driver_klass(**driver_kwargs) TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path' #128](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/issues/128)*. Please note I'm using [Scrapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapy) to create web scrapers and Selenium to interact with the website.

- go to ton77v's commit [5c3fe7b](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/5c3fe7b43ab336349ef5fdafe39fc87f6a8a8c34/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py) and copy his code in middlewares.py
- replace the middlewares.py code under the scrapy_selenium package on your local machine (for me, it was in C:/Users//AppData/Local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py)
- [optional]: I had to !pip install webdriver-manager. As well for your Scrapy spider, you need to modify the *settings.py* file (this is part of the configuration files that appear when you start a Scrapy project, like *items.py*, *middlewares.py*, *pipelines.py*, and *settings.py*). Add the following lines of code into the *settings.py* file

  - `SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'`
  - `SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = None #not actually necessary, will work even if you comment this line out`
  - `SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=[] #put '--headless' in the brackets to prevent browser popup`
- then enter `scrapy runspider <scraper_name>.py` in your terminal and enjoy!

Quick explanation of what's happening:

- you're getting Scrapy to install the BrowserDriverManager and don't have to specify the BrowserDriverManager location anymore
- the beauty is that after the first BrowserDriverManager installation, it remembers the installation location and uses the installed BrowserDriverManager for subsequent runs
- You can adapt the scraper to open other browsers by modifying middlewares.py file (get ChatGPT to do it for you XD) and changing SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = (browser name)

Answer (score 2):

#### You can try this method

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The latest Selenium doesn’t require a webdriver. You can remove *executable_url* from the argument, because you have installed the latest version of Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
# firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", str(output_directory))
firefox_profile.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip")

service = FirefoxService(firefox_profile = firefox_profile)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    service= service,
    options = firefox_options
)
```

Comment: It is not even syntactically correct: `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: Is this a completely bogus answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen maybe i copy and paste so it has indent error just fix that