# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path' error using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, typeerror, selenium-webdriver-python

I am having this problem in Whatsapp bot sending auto message in python.

Code trial:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

message = "this is message" 
amount = 50 
delay = 0.1 
contact = "person to message"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Chrome_Profile') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/') 
#driver.minimize_window() 

time.sleep(20)

name_list = []

#//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div/div/div/div[2]
#//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span

for i in range(1, 15):
    info = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[{i}]' + '/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
    name_list.append(info.text)


to_click = name_list.index(contact) + 1


driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="pane-side"]/div[1]/div/div/div[{to_click}]').click()


time.sleep(2)

#//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]

for i in range(amount):
    # Searching for text box
    text_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]')
    text_box.send_keys(message)
    text_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Monster\OneDrive\Masaüstü\UserName\SPAMBOT PYTHON\spambot.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

So far, I tried Service library instead of driver keyword but no solution.Also the same code was working until about a few months ago with no change. But when I opened it today nothing changed my code didn't work

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76550506/7058266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my earlier solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76550727/7058266, this is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `executable_path` was removed.

If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Commits in selenium-4.10.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e):

[image: executable_path]

[*executable_path*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/7429447) which was deprecated earlier is now completely removed from [***selenium-4.10.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-4.10.0) through the merge [Remove deprecated code in driver classes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/12030).

---

### Details

If you look at the [constructor](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22fL39) after *`self`*, the next argument is *`options`* followed by *`service`*.

So when you mention:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Python interpreter doesn't recognizes the keyword `executable_path` anymore and raises

```
TypeError: WebDriver.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

---

### Solution

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you have to use the key *`Service()`* . So you need to change as follows:

```
s = Service(r'C:\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
```

---

Incase you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use the *`Service()`* either as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```