# TypeError: WebDriver.init() received an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I encountered this error when I run the code I wrote in CMD.

```py
drive = web drive. Firefox(executable_path="C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe") TypeError: WebDriver.init() received an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

Code I wrote:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe")

def reset_password(username, email):
 driver.get("https://www..com/")
sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_name('Email or Username').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name('Email or Username').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_name('Email or Username').send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_name('Email or Username').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: WebDriver.\_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable\_path' error using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756479/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-p)

Answer (score 0):

You need to **create** a **Firefox Service** first

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

path = "C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe"        

firefox_service_obj = Service(path)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service_obj)
```