# How to find and extract a timestamp on a HTML-Website with Python/BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, timestamp

I'm trying to write a bot that sends an email when there is a warning from the German Weather Service (Deutsche Wetterdienst DWD). This bot will be implemented in Python on my Raspberry Pi.

I want to extract some information from the DWD Website for, let's say, Berlin. The URL could be
**https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/warnungen_gemeinden/warnWetter_node.html?ort=Berlin-Mitte**

First I want to extract the latest **timestamp** (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge224.jpg). When I examine the HTML information of this page, I find the corresponding id="HeaderBox" with the required timestamp (https://i.stack.imgur.com/spMQm.jpg).

**Unfortunately, this date and time isn't given when I pull the HTML code with Python**. So here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/warnungen_gemeinden/warnWetter_node.html?ort=Berlin-Mitte"
r = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
doctext = doc.get_text()
print(doctext)
```

The result is always just "Letzte Aktualisierung: " and an "empty" line, even when I try `last_date = doc.find(id="headerBox")`.

I am using the PyCharm IDE (community edition) and Python 3.11.

Any hints or ideas where to look are appreciated.

Best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could look at the requests sent to the server to fetch warnings.
When inspecting the network, I saw these GET request URLs:

```
https://www.dwd.de/DWD/warnungen/warnapp_gemeinden/json/warnings_gemeinde.json?jsonp=loadWarnings......
```

The response was

```
warnWetter.loadWarnings({
    "time": 1694012878000,
    "warnings": [],
    "copyright": "..."
});
```

The timestamp right there corresponds to the exact time of last update (as I checked) and does not change when the website is reloaded (unless the last update also change).

You can format it and check for yourself. Hope this helps. Cheers.

```
new Date(1694012878000).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply, it helped a lot. I got the solution close to your what you suggested. I installed chromium from the command line `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver` and added the executable to the PATH environment as shown in [1](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/).

Since Selenium has been updated, the arguments have changed a bit, as explained in [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550506/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-p).

The full code is now

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.wendriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
service = Service(executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
url = "https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/warnungen_gemeinden/warnWetter_node.html?ort=Berlin-Mitte"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
timestamp_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "headerBox")
timestamp_text = timestamp_element.text
print(timestamp_text)
driver.quit()
```