# Errors when runing a Python code containing Selenium in KNIME

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, knime

I made a code for Web Scraping with Selenium on Jupyter Notebook. It works fine. But now I need to implement it inside a Python Source Node on KNIME.

The current error that I am facing is:

> "Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000001C6DCD29B50>, but it must be an int, float or None"

The code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Configurar opções do Chrome com um timeout explícito
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--timeout=30")  # Defina um timeout de 30 segundos

# Instalar Webdriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Configurar o driver do Chrome com as opções definidas
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

# Localizar website e entrar
website = 'https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices'
driver.get(website)
# Maximizar aba Web
driver.maximize_window()
# Inplicit wait de 5 segundos para renderizar a página ao abrir
time.sleep(5)
# Localizar botão e fechar aba de Cookies da página
search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//i[@class='privacy-cookie-banner__icon-close']")
search_button.click()

# Criar listas vazias para armazenar a informação que queremos
name = []
ages = []
country = []
country_2 = []
testes = ['Brazil']

# Encontrar todos os paises no seletor de nacionalidade da página e anexá los na lista country_2
select_countries = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//select[@id="nationality"]'))

for option in select_countries.options:
    country_2.append(option.text)

# Remover o primeiro elemento da lista country_2 (é um elemento vazio)
country_2.pop(0)

# Itera pelos países na lista country_2
for pais in testes:
    select_countries.select_by_visible_text(pais)

    # Loop entre idades de 18 a 100 anos
    for age in range(18, 100):
        min_age_input = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMin"]')
        min_age_input.clear()  # Limpa o campo de idade mínima
        min_age_input.send_keys(str(age))  # Insere a idade mínima

        max_age_input = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMax"]')
        max_age_input.clear()  # Limpa o campo de idade máxima
        max_age_input.send_keys(str(age))  # Insere a idade máxima

        # Localiza o botão de pesquisa e clika nele
        search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//button[@id='submit' and @type='submit']")
        search_button.click()

        time.sleep(5)

        # Localiza o elemento da barra de paginação usando XPath
        pagination = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@id, "paginationPanel")]')

        # Localiza todos os elementos <li> dentro do elemento de paginação
        pages = pagination.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li')

        # Obtenha o número da primeira e última página
        initial_page = 1

        # Verifique se há pelo menos dois elementos em 'pages' antes de acessar 'pages[-2]'
        if len(pages) >= 2:
            last_page = int(pages[-2].text)
        else:
            last_page = initial_page


        # Loop While para paginar todas as paginas do Website
        while initial_page <= last_page:

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Explicit Wait para esperar os elementos desejados aparecerem na página
                container = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__list")]')))
                products = WebDriverWait(container, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__item notice_red")]')))
            except:
                pass

            # Try e Except para pular erros quando a página se encontra vazia (sem a presença de elementos para extrair)
            try:
                # Encontrar os elementos que desejamos exrair por xpath e anexar todos em suas devidas listas (criadas acima)
                for product in products:
                    name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
                    ages.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
                    country.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="nationalities"]').text)
            except:
                pass

                # Try e Except para evitar erros quando o prgrama chega na ultima aba e não existe mais o botão para uma próxima pagina
            try:
                # Encontra o botão que vai para a próxima aba (direita) e clika nele
                next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
                next_button.click()
            except:
                pass


            # Parte final da paginação, diz ao loop while para somar +1 na contagem de páginas e ir para a proxima repetição
            initial_page = initial_page + 1

# Transforma as listas já preenchidas com informação em um documento CSV, utilizando o Pandas.
max_length = max(len(name), len(ages), len(country))

while len(name) < max_length:
    name.append('')
while len(ages) < max_length:
    ages.append('')
while len(country) < max_length:
    country.append('')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name, 'Age': ages, 'Country': country})

output_table = df
```

What may be wrong? I tried to apply implicit and explicit waits, but without success.
I am new to KNIME and would appreciate some advices, if possible.

Note: I've posted this topic on KNIME forum, but had no success.

Comment: do you need the -- in front of the arg when passed in that way? check that

Comment: I fixed the problem. There were two things:

First, my Python environment had some bug. I changed it in KNIME.
Second, had some problems with the Selenium version. I used this StackOverflow post to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550506/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-p