# the command is not executing it is writing the (chrome is not callable)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pip, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.chrome("C:\Drivers\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login")
```

selenium packages not working
when i want to execute it is not working
i installed the last version of python,pycharm and selenium
my computer has windows 11 pro
i have installed the last version of chrome
i have downloded the last version of chrome,firfaxe and edge drivers
but i am trying to execute it the system is writing (chrome is not callible)

Comment: it's capital C `webdriver.Chrome`

Comment: The executable path argument has been removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550506/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-p

Comment: You should use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) instead of selenium, much newer and better python library.