# TypeError: ChromeDriverManager.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to get started into Web Scraping but I got that on terminal with just this code

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ruta = ChromeDriverManager(path='./chromedriver').install
```

Error:

```
TypeError: ChromeDriverManager.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
```

Comment: I don't think the `path` argument in `ChromeDriverManager` is valid and the install method need parentheses after it. You just need to set it to be like `ChromeDriverManager().install()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: WebDriver.\_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable\_path' in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76550506/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-executable-p)